# Multiple Condition based disable of button in react-native project using expo

Tags: react-native, button, expo, state, disable

I have created an application in expo which has a form of various fields and otp verification using mail and mobile number. The submit button should be disabled initially and should only be enabled if the values are entered and both the OTPs are verified.Can someone help with the state flags in react-native?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that you're using the native `Button` component from `react-native`.

1. Use the `disabled` prop of your button component. If set to `true`, it disables all interactions for the button.

```js
<Button disabled={true} />
```

2. In a more complex scenario, you can set the disabled prop to a state variable like this.

```js
<Button disabled={buttonStatus} />
```

Here is a working example based on the `TextInput` component.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { TextInput, Button } from "react-native";

const App = () => {
  const [value, onChangeText] = React.useState("");
  const [value2, onChangeText2] = React.useState("");

  const [buttonStatus, setButtonStatus] = React.useState(true);

  const inputChangeHandler = () => {
    if (value.length > 0 && value2.length > 0) {
      setButtonStatus(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <TextInput
        style={{ height: 40, borderColor: "gray", borderWidth: 1 }}
        onChangeText={(text) => onChangeText(text)}
        onChange={inputChangeHandler}
        value={value}
      />
      <TextInput
        style={{ height: 40, borderColor: "gray", borderWidth: 1 }}
        onChangeText={(text) => onChangeText2(text)}
        onChange={inputChangeHandler}
        value={value2}
      />

      <Button
        disabled={buttonStatus}
        title="Learn More"
        color="#841584"
        accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

If you want to update the status of the button in real-time, use the `onChange` prop of TextInput, or if you want to update the status when the input focus is out of focus use `onBlur`.

Here is a live demo on [Expo](https://snack.expo.io/@ajinkabeer/flatlist)

Comment: I should disable the buttonStatus flag under my otp function as well?

Comment: @ Ajin Kabeer Thanks!! I am trying to implement. Will post here once I have checked.

Comment: Sounds good, I have updated the example with two `TextInput` components.

Comment: Yes!! I saw.Thanks

Comment: this code won't work if you hit backspace and clear any of the input, the button will not disable.

Comment: This solution is more like a generic example. You can always modify the condition and make it suitable for your use case :) @sarvagya8

Answer (score 3):

Using hooks to disable the button. The button will only enable if there no empty string in both of the inputs.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Button, Text, TextInput, View } from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  const [description, setDescription] = useState('');
  const [amount, setAmount] = useState('');
  const [disable, setDisable] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    (amount && description) ? setDisable(false) : setDisable(true);
  }, [amount, description]);

  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput value={description} placeholder='Enter a description'
        onChangeText={text => setDescription(text)} 
      />
      <TextInput value={amount} placeholder='Enter the amount in $'
        keyboardType='numeric' onChangeText={text => setAmount(text)} 
      />
      <Button disabled={disable} title='Add' />
    </View>
  )
}

export default App;
```